# How do i use HERE vector maps in Openlayer?

Tags: vector, here-api, heremaps

Is it possible to use HERE vector maps in openlayer? The example on the openlayer site uses raster maps but not vector.

Comment: Hi , HERE Vector Maps  follows the Vector Tile Specification. This format contains geometries, such as points and lines that define polygons, labels (such as road names or city names), and other kinds of data that are typically passed to a renderer to draw a map. The tiles are optimized to be visualized as 512px screen pixels per tile. I am not sure Openlayer does support Vector Tile Specification. Please have a look at about Vector Tile Specification . https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment section by [Younjae Park](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562963/using-here-vector-maps-in-openlayer/68588194#comment114233086_64562963):

> HERE Vector Maps follows the Vector Tile Specification. This format contains geometries, such as points and lines that define polygons, labels (such as road names or city names), and other kinds of data that are typically passed to a renderer to draw a map. The tiles are optimized to be visualized as 512px screen pixels per tile.
> Please have a look also a look at Vector Tile Specification of Openlayer.